# Persist java.time.Instant (JDK8) with JPA2/Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, java-8, java-time

Neither JPA nor Hibernate currently support the new date/time classes brought by JSR-310 in JDK8 (JPA [ticket](https://java.net/jira/browse/JPA_SPEC-63), Hibernate [ticket](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8844)). Nonetheless, I'd like to code with the JDK8 date/time classes as they are finally well designed. In particular, I'm interested in `java.time.Instant`, not in full support for all `java.time.*` types, as all my entities will use this particular class (or so I think now, at least :-)

One option is to write a [type converter](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/2013/10/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter.html), as defined by JPA 2.1. However, our app server is JBoss EAP 6.3 which is JPA 2.0 but not 2.1 compatible, so this is out of the question for now.

The next option is to use a Hibernate user type (a blog post about converting other JSR-310 classes [here](http://blog.progs.be/550/java-time-hibernate)).

Are there better options? Thanks.

Comment: Yes: use a library that defines these hibernate user types for you: http://jadira.sourceforge.net/index.html

Comment: I suggest you accept the answer from @PryceJS as it describes the current best practice.

Comment: Will do, thanks. Yes, times have changed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Hibernate 5.2 onwards has this issue solved more fully - you no longer need to include the `hibernate-java8` dependency from Ipandzic's comment and you can use `java.time.*` classes such as `LocalDateTime` or `Instant` without any additional steps. You also do not need to mark columns using `java.util.LocalDateTime` etc as `Temporal` anymore, the way you had to with the older `java.util.Date` approach.

Since Hibernate 5.2, the `hibernate-java8` content has been merged into `hibernate-core` [see the change notes here](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/wiki/Migration-Guide---5.2)

Answer (score 20):

Either use Hibernate 5.2.0+ or for earlier Hibernate 5 add the following dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks. I cannot yet use Hibernate 5, though, it's only in beta.

Comment: Np, you will soon. It is scheduled for release on 27/May/2015, see [here](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/projects/HHH?selectedItem=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:release-page)

Comment: Sadly, they have changed release schedule, at this time, only CR1 version is available.

Comment: Hibernate 5 is stable now, version 5.0.1

Answer (score 6):

See the [ThreeTen home page](http://www.threeten.org/), where three different JPA libraries are mentioned:

- [Jadira user type](http://jadira.sourceforge.net/usertype-userguide.html)
- [ThreeTen JPA](https://github.com/marschall/threeten-jpa)
- [JPA attribute converters](https://bitbucket.org/montanajava/jpaattributeconverters)