# Hibernate 5 java.time issue on postgres

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jodatime

Using hibernate 5 with postgresql 8.2; on a column defined as timestamp(6) I am trying to map to

```
@Column(name = "LAST_UPDATED_DATE")
private Instant lastUpdatedDate;
```

But it seems hibernate doesn't like something. The exception I get is :

> caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header:
>   32303135  at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:808)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.(ObjectInputStream.java:301)     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.(SerializationHelper.java:309)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.(SerializationHelper.java:299)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:218)
>     ... 95 more

Couldn't find out what is the issue

Comment: Did you try using `java.util.Date` ?

Comment: You're missing the jar file that adds the support for java.time types to Hibernate. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30161390/571407

Comment: That jar file is deprecated in hibernate 5.