# XMLGregorianCalendar to Date in oracle

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, xmlgregoriancalendar

I got XMLGregorianCalendar dates that i read from file:

```
<Status status="1028" timestamp="2018-03-25T01:00:00Z"/>
<Status status="1028" timestamp="2018-03-25T02:00:00Z"/>
<Status status="1028" timestamp="2018-03-25T03:00:00Z"/>
```

I need to store them in oracle database with the exactly same time. I got this field:

```
<column name="TIMESTAMP" type="DATE"/>
```

I got field in my entity:

```
@Convert(converter = XMLGregorianCalendarConverter.class)
private XMLGregorianCalendar timestamp;
```

and my converter:

```
@Converter
@Slf4j
public class XMLGregorianCalendarConverter implements AttributeConverter<XMLGregorianCalendar, Date> {

    @Override
    public Date convertToDatabaseColumn(XMLGregorianCalendar xcal) {
        return toDate(xcal);
    }

@Override
public XMLGregorianCalendar convertToEntityAttribute(Date date) {
    try {
        return toXMLGregorianCalendarWithUTCTimezone(date);
    } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

private DatatypeFactory getDatatypeFactory() throws DatatypeConfigurationException {
    return DatatypeFactory.newInstance();
}

private Date toDate(XMLGregorianCalendar calendar) {
    if (calendar == null) {
        return null;
    }

    return calendar.toGregorianCalendar().getTime();
}

private XMLGregorianCalendar toXMLGregorianCalendarWithUTCTimezone(Date date) throws DatatypeConfigurationException {

    if (date == null) {
        return null;
    }

    GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    gregorianCalendar.setTime(date);

    XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGregorianCalendar = getDatatypeFactory().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gregorianCalendar);
    xmlGregorianCalendar.setMillisecond(DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED);
    xmlGregorianCalendar.setTimezone(DatatypeConstants.EQUAL);
    return xmlGregorianCalendar;
}
```

When i save them instead of getting first, second and third hour i get:

[image]

I read a lot of answers to similar questions here but i still can't make it right because i get odd results like first, third, third hour and so on.. 
What should i change in my converter to make it work?

Comment: Those input strings are *not* “XMLGregorianCalendar dates”. They are text in standard ISO 8601 format. The *java.time* classes use these standard formats by default when parsing/generating textual representations of date-time values. `Instant.parse( "2018-03-25T01:00:00Z" )`

Comment: I know that i can convert it to Instant, but i need to save it in oracle 11g database and when i try to save it i get oracle error something like "binary or number expected". When i save it as java.util.Date then it works, but without setting default timezone to UTC i got the problem with hours

Comment: See: [*Persist java.time.Instant (JDK8) with JPA2/Hibernate*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26447464/642706)

Answer (score 0):

Ok i resolved it by adding

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

before i return java.util.Date from *toDate* method.

Comment: This is a terrible solution. Setting the default time zone immediately affects all code in all threads of all apps running within that JVM. Instead, use *java.time* classes and specify the otherwise-optional time zone arguments.

Comment: This is a very small app and it's all i need.